# MS Graph API ODATA query orderby is not working on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying a Graph endpoint with Graph Explorer, in particular, I'd like to sort by `id` by using the following URL with ODATA query but it doesn't work (Always the same result without sorting):

```
/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{id}/items?$select=id&$orderby=id desc
```

Comment: I seem to recall that `orderby` isn't supported and that it always returns them in the order defined by the default view of that list.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately not all ODATA queries are supported on all workloads on #MicrosoftGraph. It is something we're trying to standardize on. It is frustrating I know. The first thing we're doing this quarter is documenting what is actually supported to stop this confusion.